Trying to show a pop-up context menu on an NSButton within an NSMenuItem in Cocoa
I am trying to show a context menu in a macOS menu bar application when I right-click an NSButton within an NSMenuItem. The context menu appears as expected when the NSButton is placed directly on an NSView, but it does not work when I embed it in an NSMenu. Does anyone know how to make this work?
I have created a custom subclass of NSButton so that it shows a context menu on right-click.
class RightClickableButton: NSButton {
    
    override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let menu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Item", action: #selector(itemAction), keyEquivalent: ""))
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(menu, with: event, for: self)
    }
   
    @objc func itemAction() {}
    
}

A right-clickable button will be added to an NSView (in the future, I want to add multiple buttons to this NSView), and the view will be set in an NSMenuItem.
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    let statusItem: NSStatusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength);
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        let menu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        let buttonsMenuItem: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        let buttonsView: NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
        let button: RightClickableButton = RightClickableButton(title: "Button", target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction))
        button.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30)
        buttonsView.addSubview(button)
        buttonsMenuItem.view = buttonsView
        menu.addItem(buttonsMenuItem)
        statusItem.menu = menu
        statusItem.button?.title = "MenuApp"
        
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction() {}
}

The following is the image I want to achieve exactly (I am currently developing a window switcher app). After listing the windows of running applications, the user can choose to add some of them to the top of the menu. If one of them is clicked, it navigates to that application’s window. If the user wants to remove an added item, they can right-click it, and a pop-up menu to remove the item will be shown.
Visualization of what I want to achieve

So you are trying to put a button in a statusItem menu to popup another menu?

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. You could try to visualize it.

@red_menace Yes, exactly, so that I can show, e.g., a pop-up menu to remove that button.

I'm not quite understanding what you are doing.  You have a regular NSMenu you want to pop up at a NSButton when it is clicked?  What is the NSStatusItem for?

@red_menace I want to show a pop-up menu on an NSButton when it is right-clicked. I've added an image for reference.

A menu isn't a window and has its own event loop. The status item already does NSMenu.popUp(positioning:at:in:). A menu can't pop up when a menu is popped up.

Menu items with custom views didn't always receive mouse events back when menus were Carbon - not sure if that is still the case.  You might test if the rightMouseDown method is actually getting called.  Another idea would be for the statusItem to use something like a popover instead of putting the view in a menu item.
